# Access to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get access to every HTML tag one after another like collections' syntaxes(from JS)?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("*")` will give you a jQuery collection of all tags in the DOM.

Comment: How can I change focus from one tag to another using this syntax? And can I select all elements with some attribute?

Comment: Yes?  Use `$('*').each()` to iterate over them.

Comment: See the [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for the modifiers to select elements by attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("*")`
http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementsByTagName('*') in pure Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*')
```

Then if you want to choose a specific tag, `$('*')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate in plain javascript,

```
var tags = $("*");
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    // do what you want with tags[i]
    }

}
```